# Click on 1 item in jQuery selector array is applying to all elements in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a cheat function for a minesweeper game that reveals 1 random non-bomb square (line 279), along with its safe neighboring squares (any of the 8 squares around it that have no bombs).

For some reason though, doing this `$(this.nonBombCells.random()[0]).click()` is triggering ALL of the non-bomb squares to reveal (line 260), instead of just the random one and safe neighbors until a nearby bomb is encountered.

If I comment out line 279 and click a non-bomb cell, it works as intended.

I have a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OyC8LbFdsAFPn709pUiw?p=preview

How can I get this function to work properly as if a human clicked that square?

Relevant code:

```
(function($){

    // I am the controller for the mine sweeper game.
    function MineSweeper(selector, columnCount, rowCount, bombCount){
        var self = this;
        this.table = $(selector);
        this.columnCount = (columnCount || 30);
        this.rowCount = (rowCount || 30);

        // Check to see if the bomb count contains a percent sign.
        if ((typeof(bombCount) == "string") && (bombCount.indexOf("%") > 0)){
            // The bomb count is a percentage of the total number
            // of cells.
            this.bombCount = Math.floor(
                (this.columnCount * this.rowCount) *
                (parseInt(bombCount) / 100)
           );
        } else {
            // The bomb count is just a standard number.
            this.bombCount = (bombCount || 15);
        }

        // Bind the click handler for the table. This way, we
        // don't have to attach event handlers to each cell.
        this.table.click(
            function(event){
                // Pass off to the table click handler.
                self.onClick(event);
                // Cancel default event.
                return(false);
            }
       );

        // Initialize the table.
        this.initTable();
    };


    // I build the actual markup of the table using the
    // given number of columns and rows.
    MineSweeper.prototype.buildTable = function(){
        // Build the markup for a given row.
        var rowHtml = ("<tr>" + duplicateContent("<td class=\"active\">&nbsp;</td>", this.columnCount) + "</tr>");

        // Build the markup for the table using the row
        // data the given number of times.
        var tableHtml = duplicateContent(rowHtml, this.rowCount);

        // Set the HTML of the table to fill it out.
        this.table.html(tableHtml);
    };


    // I check to see if an end-game has been reached.
    // If so, then I give the option to restart.
    MineSweeper.prototype.checkEndGame = function(){
        var message = "";
        var isEndGame = false;

        // Check to see if any of the bombs have exploded.
        if (this.bombCells.filter(".bomb-revealed").size()){
            // Set the message.
            message = "You LOSE - Play Again?";
            // Flag the end game.
            isEndGame = true;
        // Check to see if there are any more active
        // non-bomb cells. If not, then the user has
        // successfully clicked all non-bomb cells.
        } else if (!this.nonBombCells.filter(".active").size()){
            // Set the message.
            message = "You WIN - Play Again?";
            // Flag the end game.
            isEndGame = true;
        }

        // Check to see if the game is over.
        if (isEndGame){
            // Prompt for replay.
            if (confirm(message)){
                // Restart the game.
                this.restart();
            }

        }
    };


    // I clear the table of any markup.
    MineSweeper.prototype.clearTable = function(){
        this.table.empty();
    };


    // I initialize the table.
    MineSweeper.prototype.initTable = function(){
        var self = this;
        // Clear the table if there is any existing markup.
        this.clearTable();

        // Now that we have ensured that the table is
        // empty, let's build out the HTML for the table.
        this.buildTable();

        // Gather the cells of the table.
        this.cells = this.table.find("td");
        // Set the "near bombs" data for each cell to
        // zero. This is the number of bombs that the cell
        // is near.
        this.cells.data("nearBombs", 0);

        // For each cell, keep a collection of the cells
        // that are near this cell.
        this.cells.each(function(index, cellNode){
            var cell = $(this);

            // Store the near cells.
            cell.data("near", cell.near());
        });

        // Randomly select and gather the bomb cells.
        this.bombCells = this.cells.randomFilter(this.bombCount).addClass("bomb");

        // Now that we've selected the bomb cells, let's
        // get teh non-bomb cells.
        this.nonBombCells = this.cells.filter(
            function(index){
                // If this cell does NOT appear in the bomb
                // cells collection, then it's a non-bomb
                // cell.
                return(self.bombCells.index(this) == -1);
            }
        );
        this.cheat();

        // Now that we have the bomb cells, let's go through
        // each of them and apply its "nearness" to the
        // cells around it.
        this.bombCells.each(
            function(index, node){
                var cell = $(this);
                var nearCells = cell.data("near");

                // For each near cell, increment the near
                // data counter.
                nearCells.each(function(){
                    var nearCell = $(this);

                    // Get the current near data and
                    // increment it.
                    nearCell.data("nearBombs", (nearCell.data("nearBombs") + 1));
                });
            }
        );
    };

    // I handle the clicks at the table level.
    MineSweeper.prototype.onClick = function(event){
        // Get the trigger for the event.
        var target = $(event.target);
        // Check to make sure the target is an active cell.
        // If it is not, then we are not interested.
        if (target.is("td.active")){ 
            // Check to see if the ALT key was pressed. If it
            // was, then we are handling the caution toggle.
            // If not, then we are going to process a normal
            // click event.
            if (event.altKey){

                // Toggle the caution nature of this cell.
                this.toggleCaution(target);

            } else {

                // Check to see if the target was a bomb cell.
                if (target.hasClass("bomb")){

                    // The user clicked on a bomb, which will end
                    // the game. Reveal the whole board (end-game
                    // check comes below).
                    this.revealBoard();

                } else {

                    // The target was not a bomb, so show it.
                    this.revealCell(target);

                }

                // Check end game.
                this.checkEndGame();

            }
        }


    };


    // I restart the game.
    MineSweeper.prototype.restart = function(){
        // Re-initialize the table.
        this.initTable();
    };


    // I reveal the entire board.
    MineSweeper.prototype.revealBoard = function(){
        // Remove the transient classes.
        this.cells.removeClass("active").removeClass("caution");

        // Add the bomb-revealed classes to the bombs.
        this.bombCells.addClass("bomb-revealed");

        // Set the cell contents.
        this.cells.each(
            function(index, cellNode){
                var cell = $(this);

                // Check to see if this is a bomb cell.
                if (cell.hasClass("bomb")){

                    // Show an *.
                    cell.html("*");

                } else if (cell.data("nearBombs")){

                    // Show the count.
                    cell.html(cell.data("nearBombs"));

                }
            }
       );
    };


    // I reveal the given cell.
    MineSweeper.prototype.revealCell = function(cell){
        var self = this;

        // Remove the active nature of the cell.
        cell.removeClass("active").removeClass("caution");
        // Check to see if the current cell is near any
        // bombs. If it is, then we'll just show the
        // current cell and it's nearness. If not, then
        // we'll continue to show the surrounding cells.
        if (cell.data("nearBombs")){
            // Set the content of the cell.
            cell.html(cell.data("nearBombs"));
        } else {
            // Make sure the cell has no markup.
            cell.html("");
            // This cell was not near any bombs. Therefore,
            // it is reasonable to assume the user would
            // quickly reveal all cells around it. As such,
            // we will do that for them.
            cell.data("near").filter(".active").each(
                function(index, cellNode){
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('bomb'))
                        self.revealCell($(this));
                }
           );
        }
    };

    // Toggle a cell with the caution symbol ("?")
    MineSweeper.prototype.toggleCaution = function(cell){
        if (cell.hasClass("caution")){
            cell.removeClass("caution");
            cell.html("&nbsp;");
        } else {
            cell.addClass("caution");
            cell.html("?");
        }
    }

    // Just don't have the patience? Me neither.
    MineSweeper.prototype.cheat = function() {
        var reveal = $(this.nonBombCells.random()[0]);
        reveal.click();
    }

    function duplicateContent(content, count){
        return new Array(count + 1).join(content);
    }

    $.fn.random = function() {
        return this.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length));
    }   

    // ------------------------------------------------------ //
    // ------------------------------------------------------ //


    // Store the mine sweeper class in the window scope so
    // that people can reach it ouside of this bubble.
    window.MineSweeper = MineSweeper;

})(jQuery);
```

**If you're having issues with the Plunker because it pops up the "You win" thing because of the problem:**

Press ESC, that's because line 279 (the problem) is causing it to click all non-bomb cells and therefore, trigger the win condition.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure quite what is going on in that "plunker," it activates as soon as the page loads and tells me I've won. You should try making as simple of an example as possible showing just the problematic piece of code.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I've got an infinite loop. It wins as soon as I start.

Comment: I'd recommend you console log four things in the problematic function. 1) the value of this 2) the value of this.nonBombCells, and 3)  this.nonBombCells.random() and 4) this.nonBombCells.random()[0]. Find out what each of these is, and you may find your problem somewhere along the line where one does not return the expected value.

Comment: @JamesG. Yea that's the problem. I'm trying to programmatically click 1 non-bomb cell, but instead, line 279 somehow ends up clicking ALL of the non-bomb cells. I feel like it has to do with the recursive call to `revealCell` on line 260, but it works perfectly fine if you comment line 279 and click a cell.

Comment: It is very hard to debug without having to setup the same in our local system, understand 300 lines of js code and then add console logs to debug. Is there anyway you can reduce the code, create a small fiddle to reproduce the exact error?

Comment: @nightgaunt The plunker has the exact problem reproduced, and from what I've been able to figure out from a bunch of `console.log`s and hairpulling, it's almost certainly to do with the recursive call to neighbouring cells for `revealCell` on line 260. Other than that I have no idea. The rest of the code is simply to build the markup for the table and detect a win/lose state.

Comment: But in the plunker, I cannot click any nonBombCell. It directly says I won.

Comment: @nightgaunt Press ESC, that's because line 279 (the problem) is causing it to click all non-bomb cells and therefore, trigger the win condition.

Comment: Ohk. I commented out this.cheat() and now I can debug.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed line 260 to  $(this).revealCell(); and it seems to work well.  Not sure if this is exactly what you were going for but I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem. When I used `this.cheat`, the `cell.data("nearBombs")` was always zero. So my guess was you are calling `this.cheat` before attaching data.

So I moved `this.cheat()` to line 155 and everything worked well.